# Connection String for SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am using this connection string for SQL Server Professional. It is ok...

```
<add name="bd1" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
 Data Source=10.180.0.2;
 User ID=sa;
 Password=1234;
 Initial Catalog=aa" />
```

But when I change for SQL Server Express 2008. Doesnt work.

String connection

```
<add name="bd1" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
 Data Source=10.180.0.8;
 User ID=sa;
 Password=1234;
 Initial Catalog=aa" />
```

I have this error

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.
```

Comment: Do you need to use a named instance on the Express connection? e.g.  10.180.0.8\SQLEXPRESS ?

Answer (score 4):

By default, SQL Server Express installs as a "named instance", as `\SQLEXPRESS`. Technically, *any* SQL server instance can be installed as a "named instance" (under any name), and SQL Server Express can be installed under a *different* name, or as the *default* instance - these are just the installer defaults, but: they are common defaults.

To connect to a "named instance" (rather than the *default* instance), the instance name must be included in the connection string - i.e.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=10.180.0.8\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=sa;...etc
```